# Como configurar idiomas em Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, globalização

Estou a configurar o `AddLocalization`
   Então o problema é que os Resources estão numa biblioteca de classes em separado do projecto e eu não sei configurar.

```
   services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Com o namespace completo não resolve? Ex.: "adota-me.shared.Linguagens"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para configurar os idiomas em asp.net core utilizei a seguinte configuração:

No ficheiro Startup

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
   services.AddLocalization(opts => {
    opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
   });

   services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(

     LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.SubFolder,
     opts => {
      opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
     })
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
  }
```

Coloquei os ficheiros de tradução aqui como mostra na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para no controlador acessar a tradução utilizei

```
private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;



public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
{   
    _localizer = localizer;
 }
```

Seguidamente para aceder a um texto especifico utilizei

```
 ViewData["Contact"] = _localizer.GetString("Contact").Value;
```

Passo para a  `ViewData["Contact"]` o campo com o nome **Contact** que se encontram nos ficheiros:

1. Controllers.HomeController.en.resx
2. Controllers.HomeController.pt-PT.resx

Estes ficheiro por sua ordem:

1. Views.Shared._Layout.pt-PT.resx
2. Views.Shared._Layout.en.resx

Afectam o ficheiro **_Layout.cshtml**

Dentro do ficheiro _Layout.cshtml  podemos para traduzir-mos dentro desse ficheiro sem existir controlador utilizamos razor

```
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
```

E para colocarmos uma variavel de tradução utilizamos por exemplo:

```
@Localizer["MenuHome"]
```

sendo que "MenuHome" é o nome da variável declarada no ficheiro **Views.Shared._Layout.en.resx** e **Views.Shared._Layout.pt-PT.resx**

Depois para ver as paginas nos diferentes idiomas basta acessar o link do seu site:
https://linkdosite/NomeControlador/NomeAction?culture=en 
Para mostrar a tradução neste caso em ingles